# Cassandra Select Query using Collection Primary Key in Where Clause

Tags: collections, cassandra, primary-key

I'm new to Cassandra and I created a table with a frozen collection as the primary key

```
cqlsh> create table rick_morty (id uuid, name text, adventure text, instigator frozen<set<text>>, PRIMARY KEY((instigator), adventure, name, id));
```

Now I want to query based on the primary key (instigator) for all of the values held in the collection. I have found that if I just wanted to query on 1 value, I can use CONTAINS 'contained_value', but I want to query on the entire collection.

I've been looking all over to figure out how to do this but I can't find the answer.

Doing something like

```
const query = 'SELECT name from rick_morty';
```

retrieves all results but I want to do something like...

```
const query = 'SELECT name from rick_morty where instigator = ["Rick", "Morty", "Beth"]';
```

to retrieve all list of names associated with that array of instigators.

Is this possible?? Did I just create my table in an improper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible??

Yes. See [#8 here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html).

"Filter data on a column of a user-defined type. Create an index and then run a conditional query. In Cassandra 2.1.x, you need to list all components of the name column in the WHERE clause."

This should work:

```
SELECT name from rick_morty where instigator = { 'Rick', 'Morty', 'Beth'};
```

Comment: wow, I feel like such a fool! I read through so much documentation but whenever I saw the "User Defined Type" I thought 'nah, I have the collection type already set, I don't need to know how to do that!' bah! Well thank you so much for the answer :D I marked it as accepted and greatly appreciate your help, kind sir!.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work,

```
SELECT name from rick_morty where instigator contains 'Rick' AND contains 'Morty';
```

But, This may not be an efficient/proper way to implement as Sets are meant to be used to store/get a set of data for a given primary key. 
So, I would recommend you to re-design the data model by denormolise the query into a an additional table in case if this requirement is one of your primary use case.

Comment: I think you're probably right about this table needing to be redone, but I marked the other answer as the accepted since it seemed to be closest to the original question. Thank you for your help! Getting to hear others opinions on this stuff is really beneficial for me.